# Explanation for integral of $f(x)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x^2}, x >0$ in the form of infinite series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

We want to find an integral for

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x^2}, x >0$$

in the form of infinite series.

We know that the e function has the following series:

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

According to the solution, we have the following:

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{2x}-1}{x^2} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^k}{k!} - 1}{x^2} = \frac{2}{x} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!} x^{k-2}$$

which we can integrate by pieces:

$$\int f(x)dx =2\ln(x) + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(k-1)k!} x^{k-1}$$

What I don't understand is how we get to

$$\frac{2}{x} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!} x^{k-2}$$

and how we get to

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(k-1)k!} x^{k-1}$$

Can someone elaborate this or include the middle steps (if there are any)?

Comment: "According to the solution, we have the following: $\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x^2} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^k}{k!}}{x^2}$": are you sure? Doesn't your solution rather say $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$? (or $-1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty$). If it doesn't, correct it (it is a misprint), and you should understand without more help why your first equation holds.

Comment: As for your second equation, imo you should have thought a little before asking: don't you know an antiderivative of $x^{k-2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one
$$ \begin{align} \frac{-1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^k}{k!}}{x^2} 
&= \frac{1}{x^2}\left(-1+1+\frac{2^1x^1}{1!}+\frac{2^2x^2}{2!}+\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^4x^4}{4!}+...\right) \\
&=\frac{2^1}{1!x}+\frac{2^2}{2!}+\frac{2^3x}{3!}+\frac{2^4x^2}{4!}+...\\
&= \frac{2}{x} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!} x^{k-2}\end{align}$$

And for the second one
$$\begin{align}\int f(x)dx 
&=\int\left(\frac{2}{x} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!} x^{k-2}\right)dx \\ 
&=\int\left(\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2^2}{2!}+\frac{2^3x}{3!}+\frac{2^4x^2}{4!}+...\right)dx \\
&=2\ln x+\frac{2^2x}{2!}+\frac{2^3x^2}{(2)3!}+\frac{2^4x^3}{(3)4!}+... \\
&=2\ln x + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(k-1)k!} x^{k-1} \\ \end{align}$$